# Object Modeling in PHP

Tags: php, perl, oop, data-modeling

I've been a procedural programmer for a long time, and I have started working in OO PHP specifically, and Perl to a lesser extent.

My query deals with a best approach and basic skills in object modeling, with the two languages mentioned above in mind. Most of the books I find out there deal with languages that I have no interest in or experience with Java, and I really would like to know if anybody out there is reading one right now, or know of one that is in the works.

I found the book [Object-Oriented PHP](http://objectorientedphp.com/) and have started reading it, but you have to read it from start to finish, and in the end it does not really help me “ponder and identify objects” when designing programming work-flows using UML, for example. My understanding and usage of UML is also not so good.

It would be nice if I could learn how to:

1. identify requirements from a system analyis point-of-view
2. determine an approach to design the object
3. create a business model representation using UML
4. fill out properties and methods à la PHP

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I see what answer you are looking for, but you definitely want to check out [Moose, the new Perl OO system](http://moose.perl.org).

The [Moose manual](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aManual) is a very good tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. Moose does look very cool - I will eventually need to play with it. To attempt to clarify my question: I am simply looking for tutorials with examples that utilize PHP (and Perl) and UML to design data/object models, which in turn highlight how classes are to be constructed in the source code. Once implemented, I would also have a schematic representation of the object/class design. As I understand it, this is a good way of getting a snapshot of a large codebase. Thanks again.